# how to keep checkbox state when page is reload with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, state, checked

I have a checkbox, I've defined two state for it, and when I reload page, this checkbox back to the default state (or unchecked). I got in trouble at the forum, but I did not get my answer. This is my code

```
    $('#mycheckbox').change(function () {
        var returnVal = ("Are " + "you sure?");
        if (returnVal) {
            postToServer($(this).prop("checked"));

        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));

        }
    });


    function postToServer(state) {
        let value = (state) ? 1 : 0;
        //alert('Posted Value: ' + value);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkbox.php',
            data: {'value': +value},
            success: function (response) {
                //handle response
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Since you're storing the value using a POST request, you'll have to retrieve that value on page load with another ajax call (should be a GET).

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `if else` in the change event handler.  It's always true

Comment: Side note; `checked` is a pre-existing property on checkbox inputs.  So `$(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));` should just be `this.checked = !this.checked`.  No need for the multiple jQuery object instantiations and method calls.

Comment: user:1586174 ,user:965834 iam not understand ours means so i ask him to writ or edit my code if our can solve my problem plz